# XML reading value s:envelope s:body

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a file XML, but I there are two first line strange, with  "<s:", 
I want to read in php the xml data in the "<OrderList>".
I have search on google and other about soap, but nothing works. I have tried, simplexml_load_file() and new DomDocument() to parse the data... snif.

Thank you for your helping.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetOrderListResponse xmlns="http://www.cdiscount.com">
         <GetOrderListResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ErrorMessage i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages"/>
            <OperationSuccess xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages">true</OperationSuccess>
            <ErrorList/>
            <SellerLogin>login</SellerLogin>
            <TokenId>???</TokenId>
            <OrderList>
               <Order>
                  <ArchiveParcelList>false</ArchiveParcelList>
                  <InitialTotalAmount>3.7</InitialTotalAmount>
                  <OrderLineList>
                     <OrderLine>
                        <AcceptationState>RefusedBySeller</AcceptationState>
                        <CategoryCode>06010701</CategoryCode>
                        <ProductEan>0123456789123</ProductEan>
                        <ProductId>3275054001106</ProductId>
                        <PurchasePrice>1.2</PurchasePrice>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <SellerProductId>REF3275054001</SellerProductId>
                        <Sku>3275054001106</Sku>
                        <SkuParent i:nil="true"/>
                        <UnitShippingCharges>2.5</UnitShippingCharges>
                     </OrderLine>
                  </OrderLineList>
               </Order>
            </OrderList>
         </GetOrderListResult>
      </GetOrderListResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML namespaces are a way to identify which format an element/attribute belongs, too.

The `s:` is a namepace alias, in this case for the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` as defined by the xmlns:s attribute on the root elmement. So `s:Envelope` and `s:Body` are in the soap namespace.

`GetOrderListResponse` has a xmlns attribute, too. This changes the namespace of elements without a prefix to `http://www.cdiscount.com`.

This is Soap, so using the [Soap extension](http://de.php.net/soap) classes would be a good idea.

If you like to use DOM and query the data directly, you have to take the namespaces into account.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// register OWN namespace aliases for the xpath
$xpath->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('cd', 'http://www.cdiscount.com');

// get all order nodes in "http://www.cdiscount.com" namespace
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//cd:Order', NULL, FALSE) as $order) {
  // fetch the InitialTotalAmount as a number
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('number(cd:InitialTotalAmount)', $order, FALSE));
}
```

Output:

```
float(3.7)
```